# Accessing environment variables in python

Tags: python

Why does this not print out 'xxx'?

```
$ SECRET_KEY='xxx' python -c 'import os; print os.environ['SECRET_KEY']'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'SECRET_KEY' is not defined
```

Answer (score 2):

You're shell quoting is off and as a result, python sees:

```
import os; print os.environ[SECRET_KEY]
```

(note the missing quotes).  This should work:

```
SECRET_KEY='xxx' python -c "import os; print os.environ['SECRET_KEY']"
```

should work.

Comment: That's it.  I need more coffee.

Comment: Try chai tea :-)...  That's what I'm drinking (Yum!)